# Python - Merging all xlsx files in a directory into a single file

Tags: python, pandas, merge, xlsx

The following error message continues to appear for a script I have. Any suggestions for how I can fix the problem?

**Error message:**

```
File "c:/Users/alexl/Documents/ST/mergetool.py", line 8, in <module>
    for file in glob.glob(f+".xlsx"):
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

**Script**

```
import glob    
import os    
import pandas as pd    
cwd = "C:/Users/alexl/Documents/ST/Results/"    
f = os.listdir(cwd)  
output = pd.DataFrame()    
for file in glob.glob(f+".xlsx"):    
    df = pd.read_excel(file)    
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)    
    df = pd.concat(all_data, ignore_index=True)    
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Merged.xlsb")    
df.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1")  
writer.save()
```

Comment: Your first Problem which you issue is the concatenation of the file ```f```, which is a list with the str ```.xlsx```. If ```f```is a string in this situation you would get a step further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you use `glob` to the location, not the list of items in that directory (which is the result of os.listdir(cwd):

```
for file in glob.glob(cwd+"/*.xlsx"):
```

Comment: Thanks all. The above makes sense. I know run into the issue that .xlsx files are not supported now. Is there a library I can use that will support xlsx files? 




raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported